# Using parameters from select statement inside case statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, column-alias

I have the following query

```
SELECT product.*,
(SELECT bid FROM server1 WHERE product_id = product.id) AS bid1,
(SELECT bid FROM server2 WHERE product_id = product.id) AS bid2,
CASE
    WHEN bid1 > bid2 THEN '1 wins'
    WHEN bid2 > bid1 THEN '2 wins'
    ELSE 'undecided'
END AS bid_status
FROM product
WHERE id= $1
```

This query throws error in CASE statement saying `bid1` column does not exist. How do I pass in the sub-query as a variable for the case statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scope issue. Wrap your query up as a derived table first:

```
select dt.*
    CASE
        WHEN bid1 > bid2 THEN '1 wins'
        WHEN bid2 > bid1 THEN '2 wins'
        ELSE 'undecided'
    END AS bid_status
from
(
SELECT product.*,
    (SELECT bid FROM server1 WHERE product_id = product.id) AS bid1,
    (SELECT bid FROM server2 WHERE product_id = product.id) AS bid2,
FROM product
WHERE id= $1
) dt
```